# R dynamic columns names based on another column

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a table as such:

```
types <- c("ENR","ENR","ENR","ENR","ENR","ENR")
records <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2)
occur <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2)
myval <- c("ABC|123","DEF|456","GHI|789","JKL|123","MNO|456","PQR|789")

mydf <- data.frame(types, records, occur, myval)


type   record   occur    myval
ENR    1        1        ABC|123
ENR    1        2        DEF|456
ENR    1        3        GHI|789
ENR    1        4        JKL|123
ENR    2        1        MNO|456
ENR    2        2        PQR|789
```

I am parsing out the myval column so that the delimited fields get their own columns, here's what I've used so far

```
library(tidyr)
mydf <- mydf %>% separate(myval, c("letters","numbers"),"\\|")
```

This essentially works, it creates this:

```
  types records occur letters numbers
1   ENR       1     1     ABC     123
2   ENR       1     2     DEF     456
3   ENR       1     3     GHI     789
4   ENR       1     4     JKL     123
5   ENR       2     1     MNO     456
6   ENR       2     2     PQR     789
```

.... However, I'd like the column names to be dynamic based on the occur#, so I'd ideally like this:

```
 types records occur letters1 numbers1  letters2  numbers2  letters3 numbers3 letters4 numbers4
 ENR         1     1      ABC      123
 ENR         1     2                         DEF       456
 ENR         1     3                                             GHI      789
 ENR         1     4                                                              JKL      123
 ENR         2     1      MNO      456
 ENR         2     2                         DEF       456
```

any idea how to accomplish this? I'm thinking if I can just dynamically name the columns that'd work perhaps?

Comment: Have a look at `?tidyr::spread` and `?data.table::dcast`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table` which can take multiple `value.var` columns

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(mydf), types + records + occur ~ occur, value.var = c("letters", "numbers"), fill="")
#   types records occur letters_1 letters_2 letters_3 letters_4 numbers_1 numbers_2 numbers_3 numbers_4
#1:   ENR       1     1       ABC                                     123                              
#2:   ENR       1     2                 DEF                                     456                    
#3:   ENR       1     3                           GHI                                     789          
#4:   ENR       1     4                                     JKL                                     123
#5:   ENR       2     1       MNO                                     456                              
#6:   ENR       2     2                 PQR                                     789
```

Comment: perfect, thank you!  however, I must admit, as much as I thought out this question before I posted it, I'm not certain now. I'm now thinking I'd like a single row per record: so record 1 would parse out with 4 sets of columns of letters and numbers. record 2 would parse out populating letters1 & 2 and numbers 1&2, but would leave 3 & 4 null .... hmmmm.

Regardless - thank you, your solution is working perfectly for me!

Comment: @fleetmack From your comments it is not clear.  Can you post that as a new question if that qualifies as a new set of rules

Comment: Sure, I'm tidying up some loose ends on the data right now, if I can't figure it out I'll post a new question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tidyr::spread()`

```
mydf %>% dplyr::mutate(letters_ = occur, numbers_ = occur) %>%
  spread(letters_, letters, fill = "", sep = "") %>%
  spread(numbers_, numbers, fill = "", sep = "")
```

In order to keep the orignal `occur` variable I tripled it and then, using `spread()` function, pivoted the values of letters and numbers according to the occur copies values.

Note that using the `sep` argument pastes the key and value in the new variable names. The `fill` argument is just used to get the desired output.

```
  types records occur letters_1 letters_2 letters_3 letters_4 numbers_1 numbers_2 numbers_3 numbers_4
1   ENR       1     1       ABC                                     123                              
2   ENR       1     2                 DEF                                     456                    
3   ENR       1     3                           GHI                                     789          
4   ENR       1     4                                     JKL                                     123
5   ENR       2     1       MNO                                     456                              
6   ENR       2     2                 PQR                                     789
```